# How to impose rules of indexed variables?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to use the following rule:

```
x[b,c,d]+x[a,c,d]+x[a,b,d]+x[a,b,c]->0
```

for all distinct integers a,b,c,d to simplify a messy expression with terms like

```
(x[b,c,d]+x[a,c,d]+x[a,b,d]+x[a,b,c])(x[i,j,k]+x[l,m,n])
```

but less recognizable.

I hope to find a way to define the rule so that I can use

```
FullSimplify[expression]/.r
```

However, it seems like I can only define r with a specific {a,b,c,d}. Is there a way to get a generic r that covers all {a,b,c,d}s?

Any help would be appreciated:D

Comment: Can you show what code you have tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "impose rules". You are going to solve an equation subject to that constraint? You are trying to simplify an expression according to that rule? Etc.? Each different thing you might do requires a different implementation in *Mathematica*, so can you be more specific? As an example: include a sample input with the desired output.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated my question. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Subsets`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html) and [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) as follows:

```
Total[Subsets[x[a, b, c, d], {3}]] == 0
```

> x[a, b, c] + x[a, b, d] + x[a, c, d] + x[b, c, d] == 0

**Update:** A function that constructs the desired expression:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[a_: x] := EqualTo[0] @* Total @* Map[Apply[a]] @* Subsets
```

***Examples:***

```
f[][{a, b, c, d}, {3}]
```

> x[a, b, c] + x[a, b, d] + x[a, c, d] + x[b, c, d] == 0

```
f[z][{a, b, c, d}, {2}]
```

> z[a, b] + z[a, c] + z[a, d] + z[b, c] + z[b, d] + z[c, d] == 0

```
f[w][{a, b, c, d}, {1, 2}]
```

> w[a] + w[b] + w[c] + w[d] + w[a, b] + w[a, c] + w[a, d] + w[b, c] + 
>         w[b, d] + w[c, d] == 0

**Update 2:** You can use the expression produced by `f` as the second argument of `FullSimplify`:

```
expression = (x[b, c, d] + x[a, c, d] + x[a, b, d] +  x[a, b, c]) (x[i, j, k] + x[l, m, n]);

FullSimplify[expression, f[][{a, b, c, d}, {3}]]
```

> 0

**Update 3:** Similarly you can define a function that generates the desired `Rule` which can be used with `ReplaceAll`:

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[a_: x] := Rule[#, 0] &@*Total@*Map[Apply[a]]@*Subsets
```

***Examples:***

```
rule = f2[][{a, b, c, d}, {3}]
```

> x[a, b, c] + x[a, b, d] + x[a, c, d] + x[b, c, d] -> 0

```
expression /. rule
```

> 0